# Visual Studio menu is missing the "Clean" option?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have a metadata file error that I am attempting to fix.  One of the solutions that I want to attempt is to individually clean and rebuild the projects.  I see two solutions that should work:

1. Right click on the project individually and select clean.
2. select the project, select build from the menu, select clean 'projectname'

The problem that I have is that the right click context menu is not showing clean.  It shows build and rebuild *but not clean*.

In the build menu, it only shows options to clean / build the entire solution, no matter what I currently have selected.

I have done the rebuild on each project individually, but the Metadata error is still there.

**What can  I do to get the options to clean an individual project?**

Comment: What kind of project is it?

Comment: WPF / C#.  about 6 projects in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do a "manual" clean of a project by deleting both bin and obj -folders from the projects folder. Sometimes the Clean-feature in Visual Studio doens't do decent enough job so I do this:

[image]

Note: Sometimes Visual Studio is using files from these folders so you can't have the project open and delete. Close Visual Studio and delete the folders by hand from the folder and reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: this worked for me.  And Somehow the clean option showed back up on the context menu after doing it manually once.  Life is weird.